# Java.util.Collection overrides spliterator()

Tags: java, collections

In the source code of `Collection<E>`, I am wondering why the   `@Override` annotation is used. The `spliterator()` method doesn't come from `Iterable<E>`, and `Object` doesn't have it either.

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    @Override
    default java.util.Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return java.util.Spliterators.spliterator(this, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterable DOES HAVE spliterator. Check javadoc for java8 not the previous ones

Comment: Yes, I was looking at Java8 Collection, but Java7 Iterable<E>